# Post data after ajax get using asp.net ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I get list of data through `Ajax` call like this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hashtag = 'dilwale'
    var accessToken = '16741082.1b07669.121a338d0cbe4ff6a5e04543158a4f82'
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/' + hashtag + '/media/recent?count=33&access_token='+ accessToken +'',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
        //Here I want to post data in database through ajax call Instead of showing
            for (x in data.data) {
                if (data.data[x].type == 'video') {
                    $('.instagram').append('<div style="border:1px solid orange"><video controls><source src="' + data.data[x].videos.standard_resolution.url + '" type="video/mp4"></video><span style="border:1px solid orange; dislay:block">Test1</span></div>');
                } else if (data.data[x].type == 'image') {
                    $('.instagram').append('<div style="border:1px solid orange"><img src="' + data.data[x].images.standard_resolution.url + '" ><span style="border:1px solid orange; display:block">"' + data.data[x].caption.text + '"</span><span style="border:1px solid orange; dislay:block">Test1</span></div>');
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
    })
});
```

For Inserting data function is as follows

```
function InsertData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "Default.aspx/SaveData",
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            // Show data after success
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error while Showing update data");
        }
    });
}
```

Here I have to save list of data.
My Webmethod to save data is as follows

```
[WebMethod]    
public static void SaveData(Document objDocs) //I have taken a class Document 
{     
   //Saving data in database   
}
```

I am not able to make it properly to save data after get and then show in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code below to pass the Document data from ajax:

```
//C# start
//Sample Document class
public class Document
{
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string Definition { get; set; }
}

//Javascript start
//Use JSON.stringify to make a valid json string.
var data = JSON.stringify(
    {
        objDocs: { //objDocs should be same in SaveData method Document parameter
            DocumentId: 1,
            Definition: 'Test'
        }
    }
);

//ajax call to pass Document data
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'Default.aspx/SaveData',
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```